# Can a free particle ever emit a particle?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, kinematics, conservation-laws

I have found this question here [Can a free particle absorb/emit photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81448/), along with other resources that show a free particle cannot emit a photon (in a vacuum).

Now, I am 90% sure it does, but does this result hold generally, ie not just photons/ photons but in a medium?

If you go in the rest frame no matter what it emits energy is not conserved.  The reason I am questioning this is that an exam question said 'if it can emit it find the angle relative to the motion of the electron'.  Seems odd that they would give away marks for just repeating that it can't.

Comment: How about a free neutron decaying to a proton, electron & antineutrino?

Comment: But then it changes rest mass, it doesn't just emit things

Comment: The question  is not explicit about refering to spontaneous decay or emission of photons by free electrons that are accelerated (in colliders). Have you considered "Bremsstrahlung" (if yes, the answer to the question is clearly yes). - Did you do some research on exchange of momemtum between the electron and the particle it is "braked" by. According to the graphic at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung  showing "electron deflected in the electric field" the electron interacts with the field without exchange of momentum which just can't be true (I'm new to).

Comment: What is meant by "free", what is meant by "emission"? Considering answers given there may be a question about "spontaneous decay" of a free electron, does it exist or not. Again, is the question about decay?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

True and true - there is no contradiction here.

The complete answer is contained in the answer to linked question:

> This is because energy and momentum are not both conserved if a free
>   charged particle (say, an electron) emits a photon

and the comment to that answer:

> Note that if the particle has internal structure, this argument can
>   fail. For example, atomic nuclei emit gamma rays. This is because they
>   have more than one internal state with different energies.

Applying these **two** principles we arrive at:

1. A single free electron **cannot** emit a photon
2. A single free hydrogen atom with electron in an excited state **can** emit a photon by spontaneous emission
3. A single free nucleus **can** emit a photon again by relaxation of its internal structure.

**Note**: In this answer I have only considered the dynamical restrictions involved in emitting a single photon. As pointed out in the comments there are many more complex decay processes of either elementary (e.g. tau) or composite (e.g. neutron) particles which may result in the emission of a photon as one of many decay products.

Comment: What about lepton decay, say the Tau particle decaying into an electron and a few neutrinos? I think it's not that much about elementarity but rather about the existence of a final state which in particular has a lower total mass than the initial state. edit: However, the argument makes sense if you modify it a little: An elementary particle can only decay into different particles which would not fit into the "emission" picture. In order to emit something, it needs to be a compound particle such that some interaction energy is involved which can be used to ensure energy conservation.

Comment: @Photon OK yes there is more to it: the original linked question referred to a single particle emitting a single photon without changing. The two quotes I gave are still correct.

Comment: Yes, energy-momentum (4-momentum) should be conserved, that's why I wrote "in particular". My only point was that it is necessary to differentiate more clearly between a decay and a particle emission. But maybe your answer does so sufficiently, I might have read it not carefully enough and identified decay and particle emission which is clearly wrong here. My bad, sorry for the possible confusion!

Comment: @Photon I think your comment was very pertinent - I learnt from it thanks.

Comment: In your final example (v1), do you have in mind neutron beta decay? That is a different argument since there are multiple, massive decay products emitted, and beta emission can occur in structureless particles like the muon and tau. If you meant that a free neutron may emit a photon, that's not correct for the same reason that a free electron can't emit a photon. If you meant that a free *nucleus* may relax by emitting a photon due to its internal structure, you should edit to clarify.

Comment: @rob thanks: I have tried to edit to capture the main points of your and Photon's feedback - please reply if I can clarify further (without turning answer into a complete survey of particle physics!)

Answer (score 1):

> If you go in the rest frame no matter what it emits energy is not conserved.

But note that this argument fails if the parent particle is massless, since then there is no such rest frame. A gluon can decay into two gluons. See [Decay of massless particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12488/decay-of-massless-particles) .

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be found on Wikipedia's page

[**Electron scattering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_scattering#Bremsstrahlung_scattering)

in the explanation of ***Synchrotron emission***:

"If a charged particle such as an electron is accelerated – this can be acceleration in a straight line or motion in a curved path – electromagnetic radiation is emitted by the particle. (...)

Robert Langmuir is credited as recognizing it as synchrotron radiation or, as he called it, "Schwinger radiation" after Julian Schwinger. (...)

Within a circular orbit such as a storage ring, the non-relativistic case *is simply the centripetal acceleration*."

Different from [Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) where electrons are defracted by the electromagnetic-field of a particle which in that case is an atom,  "Schwinger radiation" shows that there are no defracting "third" particles needed for an electron to emit a particle which is a photon.

A free electron can emit a photon simply by being accelerated.

Comment: I like Langmuir for "The Arrangement of Electrons in Atoms and Molecules" in which, building on Gilbert N. Lewis's cubical atom theory and Walther Kossel's chemical bonding theory, he outlined his "concentric theory of atomic structure". [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irving_Langmuir)